# Do you have to provide fingerprints when travelling to Bali? Do I need a visa?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, indonesia, bali

I am looking to travel to Bali in the coming months. 
Do foreigners have to provide fingerprints when travelling to Bali?  Is a visa required?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: I would be travelling from US.

Comment: @user102194 This is not quite important. The question is what citizenship you have. Are you a US-American or do you hold another citizenship? Living in the US does not imply US-citizenship.

Comment: Assuming you’re a US citizen, the purpose and length of your planned trip will affect whether you need a visa https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Indonesia.html

Comment: What country issued your passport?

Comment: @DCTLib And flying from the US doesn't imply living there!

Answer (score 3):

Whether you need a visa to enter a country is determined by your citizenship (i.e., what passport you carry, and/or in some cases, what country's travel document you carry), as well as what country you're flying from and in what country you reside.

If an airline passenger is refused entry into a country, the airline will be fined and also is required to return the passenger to his or her point of departure *at the airline's expense*, although the airline may try to recover the cost from the passenger. Thus, airlines are very careful to review passengers' travel documents before allowing them to board.

Airlines use the [Timatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timatic) database to present passenger-specific information based on the data mentioned above. [Here's  a link](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html) to access Timatic; there are others as well.

You haven't told us your passport or travel document country or country of residence, so we can't answer your question about needing a visa. You can input your information to the second link above, and see what Timatic (and, therefore, your air carrier) will require.